# Should I use 15 amp breaker with 6awg wire?

Tags: circuit-breaker

I have a 100amp main service panel in my single dwelling unit and a 60amp sub-panel in my garage. Because I no longer need the panel in the garage, I want to abandon it and replace it with a new sub-panel in the main house close to the main panel (I'm out of spaces in the main panel).

Can I use the existing #6 wire that's feeding the garage sub-panel to feed the new sub-panel and use a 15amp breaker located in the (*main panel or sub-panel*) on it?

Comment: I've tried to clarify your question to make it more readable. It was a bit confusing. Please read my edits to ensure I've not misrepresented any of your facts or your question. The one thing I wasn't clear on is where the 15a breaker is going to be - in the main panel as the feed to the sub, or as a "main" breaker in the sub panel. Please [edit] the post to indicate that bit.

Answer (score 4):

Well, it won't fit on the breaker.  Or a 20A receptacle.

You will need to pigtail the 6 AWG down to a 10 AWG to get it to go on a breaker, and 12 AWG to get it to go on a receptacle.

Since it's all 10-12 AWG, and that's allowed 20A, you might as well use a 20A breaker.

15A receptacles are allowed on 20A breakers.  (UL requires they be internally rated for 20A). The only real difference 15 vs 20A recep is the T-shaped neutral.

Note that if the wires are ***black-white-bare***, those must be used for **hot-neutral-ground**, *even if  they were't before*.   That means you may need to move the hot wire off the breaker.

---

As far as reusing the panel, most 60A panels are *way too small*.  If there's anything we've learned around here  helping people, it's that people always run out of breaker spaces *much sooner than they expected*.  As such, **a subpanel is NO place to scrimp!** Buy a huge subpanel that will far exceed your needs, that you'll never, ever fill up.  The cost is small - *spaces are cheap*.

As far as the subpanel in the garage, honestly, I'd consider leaving it put.  The X-factor is electric cars.  They're really taking off, for real this time! :)  **As such, having 50A+ in the garage adds value to your house**.

I'm sure the 60A garage panel is a tiny thing... I'd have you spend $60 or so on a new 20-24 space panel.  I'm very reluctant to "spend people's money" unnecessarily, but this is one cost you will not regret in the long term.

As far as a 15A circuit in the garage, just add a 15A breaker to the garage subpanel.

Comment: Recently in pricing sub panels I found less than $20 between 6 breaker panels and 24 breaker panels.